# How can I get a working keepassx in a xenial libertine container on my M10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10

I have an M10 tablet on the rc-proposed channel with a xenial libertine container with keepassx.

```
libertine-container-manager create -d xenial -i x3 -n 'Xenial Container'
libertine-container-manager install-package -i x3 -p keepassx
```

I installed the deb libertine-scope on my phablet

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo apt-get install libertine-scope
```

When I launch keepassx from the scope, a keepassx window pops up and then vanishes.

All I see in the log is

```
From file /home/phablet/.cache/upstart/application-legacy-x3_keepassx_0.0-.log:
Libertine Dbus session bridge socket is not ready.  Waiting...
proot info: proot info: pid 27414: terminated with signal 11pid 27415: terminated with signal 11

Libertine Dbus session bridge socket is not ready.  Waiting...
proot info: pid 27607: terminated with signal 11
proot info: pid 27609: terminated with signal 11
```

I'm not familiar with the internals enough to know what this means so that I can troubleshoot it.

How do I get this version of keepassx working?

(I ran through getting the vivid keepassx package working, but the process of exporting my kdbx to and converting it with a script to get xml to be imported in to the old version of keepassx didn't work).